# Table overlaps footer/header in RML report

Tags: report, odoo, openerp-7, reportlab, rml

I've created a custom invoices report in OpenERP v7, but I have a problem, because the table with the list of products, overlaps the footer and the header from the second page (when there's more than one page).

How can I avoid this?